# Issues with horizontal scroll gallery on mobile view

Tags: html, css, mobile, web, horizontal-scrolling

I'm having just a slight issue with a horizontal gallery on my photography website. 
[www.philippamichael.com](http://www.philippamichael.com/)

The horizontal gallery works great when viewing on a computer, all of the images are the same height.  However, when looking on a mobile phone, the images are all different sizes?

Here's screenshot of the issue -

[image]

It only happens when landscape and portrait images are in the same gallery. Can anyone tell me why this is happening, when in the code, the gallery and image height are both set to 700px.

Here is my CSS and HTML code for the horizontal scroll gallery -

```
    #scroll {
    margin-top:-2em;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    height:700px;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto; 
    overflow-y: hidden;
    -ms-overflow-y: hidden;
    }


 <div id="scroll">
 <img src="images/work/studio/nuno.jpg">
 <img src="images/work/studio/izabelle.jpg">
 <img src="images/work/studio/katie.jpg">
 </div>
```

I'm not a code wizard so maybe there is something I have missed or typed in wrongly? Or maybe I need additional code for mobile use?

Appreciate any advice, 
Philippa

Answer (score 0):

Try to attribute a fixed height for every image inside your scroller.

```
#scroll img {
    height: 700px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Let me know if it works.